# I am trying to resize my duallist box with help of size option in lightning and it is not working

Tags: apex, lightning, controller, helper

The size is not resizing the width of the list. Not working as given in the specification.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/example

Comment: What is not working? I tried this code and found it working. Share the code what you tried so far?

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks for your response it's working now as I used SIZE attribute.

Comment: Use my custom component - has drag and drop and click to move - it's way better and you can customize it. https://github.com/rapsacnz/OrderedListGroup